# JOptionPane.JOptionDialog get value of input for use in if statements

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a program that has 2 options in an option dialog and one option should execute one part, the other should execute another part. (I will do this with if statements)

```
Object reply1;  //Variable that Should be not an object???

    Object[] option = { "Choose a Random Number", "Input a Number"};   //option labels

    JOptionPane pane1;
    pane1 = new JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
        "Text explaining which option to choose\n",
        "Title",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null,
        option,
        option[0]);

           reply1 = pane1.getInputValue();  //this is the problem.
```

How do I set a variable to equal a the option chosen and what type of variable should it be?

It has been initialized as an int, String, and Object when I was debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use an `int` return value:

```
int reply1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
   "Text explaining which option to choose\n",
   "Title",
   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
   JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
   null,
   option,
   option[0]);

   if (reply1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      // option 1
   } else if (reply1 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
      // option 2
   }
```

Related: [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Comment: If I have a custom text label on each option, how do I know which is yes and which is no?

Comment: The labels don't matter as you're using `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`, yes is 0, no is 1.